# SQL : How to extract particular value from a key in data dictionary

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

I want to extract only city values from the below given data structure using Oracle SQL query.

Ex: {"firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","street2":null,"city":"Milton"}

PS: The function: json_value is not working and other threads are suggesting solution in Python. I want to use SQL only.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean this is not a JSON data structure? The example you provided IS a JSON object and can be used with JSON_VALUE: `SELECT json_value ('{"firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","street2":null,"city":"Milton"}','$.city') FROM DUAL;`

Comment: If this is not a json, then please clarify what is "data dictionary" and what "below structure" represents. What is the rule to extract some value?

Answer (score 0):

With sample data you posted, one option might be this:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{"firstName":"Curtis","street2":null,"city":"Milton"}' from dual union all
  3     select '"lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","city":"Los Angeles"}' from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_replace(substr(col, instr(col, 'city') + 7), '[^[:alnum:] ]', '') result
  6  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Milton
Los Angeles

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- `substr` finds the 1st position of the `city` string and adds 7 to it (to skip `city` itself, double quotes and the colon sign) and - as a result - returns everything to the end of the string

  - it means that city *must* be the last info in the string
- `regexp_replace` removes anything but alphanumerics and spaces
- what remains is city name (i.e. the final result)

---

As you changed your mind (so that `city` isn't the last information in the string), one option might be a nested `SUBSTR`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{"firstName":"Curtis","street2":null,"city":"Milton"}' from dual union all
  3     select '"lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","city":"Los Angeles"}' from dual union all
  4     select '"firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","street2":null,"city":"Milton","state":"FL","zip":"32583","country":"USA","phone":"' from dual
  5    )
  6  select
  7    substr(substr(col, instr(col, 'city') + 7),                 -- everything that follows "city"
  8           1,                                                   -- starting from the 1st position
  9           instr(substr(col, instr(col, 'city') + 7), '"') - 1  -- up to the first double quote in that "everything that follows "city"" substring
 10          ) result
 11  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Milton
Los Angeles
Milton

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if we want to retrieve the value of a key which is not last in the sequence. 

If suppose the example becomes: 

Address: {"firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","street2":null,"city":"Milton","state":"FL","zip":"32583","country":"USA","phone":""}

Then the solution above is giving everything starting Miltonstate.....USAphone.

Comment: Well, all we know is what you tell us. You never said that CITY could be elsewhere but the last information in the string. Anyway: I edited the answer and added another example; have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If your value is JSON-like (but is not quite so you cannot parse it using JSON functions) then you can parse a JSON-like key-value pair using:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         value,
         '[,{]\s*"city"\s*:\s*"((\\[\/"bfnrt]|\\u[0-9a-fA-Z]{4}|[^\])*)"',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS city
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '{"firstName":"Curtis","lastName":"C Fugatt","street1":"4146 Audiss Rd.","street2":null,"city":"Milton"}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '{
  "not_this_one":
    "city",
  "big_city":
    "there",
  "little_city":
    "somewhere",
  "city":
      "here"
}' FROM DUAL;
```

*Note: in the second example, you cannot naively look for `city` or `"city"` as it will match a value rather than a key.*

Outputs:

> | CITY |
> | --- |
> | Milton |
> | here |

---

However, if it is JSON data (which your sample is) then you can (and should) use JSON functions to parse it:

```sql
SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.city') AS city
FROM   table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=def3ba9e2a2210b4367bc6e5e21ce243)*

Comment: SELECT JSON_VALUE(value, '$.city') AS city
FROM   table_name; 

This is not working as may be because city is in double quotes.

Comment: @MishitaAgarwal In JSON, the keys and values **MUST** be in double quotes. They are in double quotes in your sample data and in the sample data in my answer (where the first row was a copy/paste of your data). My queries both work on your data; if you have data where it is not working then please provide a [MRE] because I cannot replicate what you say in your previous comment.